# Retrieving documents which not contains a a field with boolean value

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Assuming we have a collection with data like the following:

```
{
   "_id":"4313e7aa192d75b7c3cffc8af0312fdeb",
   "name":"Foo",
   "services":[
      {
         "serviceID":"378e7aa192d75b7c3cffc8aq033fdeb",
         "isActive":true
      },
      {
         "serviceID":"5403e7aa192d75b7c3cffc8af033fdex",
         "isActive":false
      },
      {
         "serviceID":"e918e7aa192d75b7c3cffc8ax0233fdey",
         "isActive":true
      }
   ]
},
{
   "_id":"b1d8b857963e35521faef87d215ca3f7",
   "name":"Foo",
   "services":[
      {
         "serviceID":"b98857963e35521faef87d215ca3f8",
         "isActive":false
      }
   ]
},
{
   "_id":"34efdb9e62c2131e050917b4524d6e6f",
   "name":"Foo",
   "services":[
      {
         "serviceID":"39efba9e62c2131e050917b4524d6e6f",
         "isActive":false
      },
      {
         "serviceID":"34ex1b9e62c2131e050917b4524d6e6x",
         "isActive":false
      }
   ]
}
```

Now, how we can make a query for retrieving documents which have not any active services (I mean documents which not contains `"isActive":true`)? Is there any operator for a such query?

Any ideas would be appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

How about something as simple as this:

```
collection.find( { "services.isActive": { $ne: true } } )
```

Answer (score 0):

If in the result documents you don't mind seeing in the services array also the ones where **isActive=true**, then what @dnickless wrote is enough.

If you do mind, try this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
    $unwind: "$services"
},
{
    $match: {
      "services.isActive": false 
    }
}
])
```

Answer (score 0):

According to description as mentioned in above question please try executing following aggregate query into MongoDB shell

```
db.collection.aggregate(

    // Pipeline
    [
        // Stage 1
        {
            $unwind: "$services"
        },

        // Stage 2
        {
            $match: {
            $or:[
            {'services.isActive':{$exists:false}},
            {'services.isActive':false}

            ]
            }
        },

    ]



);
```

The above mentioned aggregate query executes multiple stages of aggregation pipeline

$unwind operator splits an array into separate documents for each element of array.

$match operator filters documents consisting of key **isActive** with value false or either **isActive** key does not exist into document from returned result set through execution of $unwind stage.